# Display too many buttons in zoomable layout [UWP]

Tags: c#, performance, optimization, layout, uwp

I have to make an UWP app where users are able to see all the seats of large halls for cinema and then reserve chosen seats. I display a seat as a button, because I want it to be clickable and I change color when it is selected. And I may have to display more than 800 buttons for some halls. For large halls it is impossible to see seats well and select them on mobile devices, so I use ScrollViewer to allow zooming. Using all these is very bad for performance. Most phones scroll too slow with lag, and on tablets screen size changing causes lag as well. What should I do to make this scrolling, zooming and displaying too many controls very smooth and fast?

I thought about some kind of game engine frameworks but I dont know which of them are easy to use and interminable with UWP apps.

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you use incremental loading. In that way you will load only the amount you need and when the user scrolls down you will load more items..

Comment: @HasanHasanov The problem is that on the first launch of that page, all the seats (buttons) are visible and zoomed out. To let the user see the whole hall.

Answer (score 0):

If the physical area of the seat is less than can be selected with finger then you should zoom on a graphic layout. Else use your buttons when your zoomed enough to actually select them.

Pseudo code

```
if (seat.area < finger.area) {
  draw_graphic
  touch_zoom_here
} else {
  draw_button
  touch_select
}
```